# Removing an item from a list in a recycleview

Tags: android

I have a list of users, and I want to hide every user with admin role when show it in recycleview. Tried to use `for` method, but the app ended up crash. here is the code that I tried to use

```
 public void setUserList(List<UserModel> userList) {
    this.userList = userList;
    //userList.remove(0);
    for(int i=0;i<=userList.size();i++)
    {
        if(userList.get(i).getRole().equals("admin")) {
            userList.remove(i);
        }
    }
    //userList.removeIf(userModel -> userModel.getRole().matches("admin"));
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

For now, because the user with role admin always located at first index of array, I use `userList.remove(0);` but if any of you have better approach, I really apreciate it. Thank you.

Edit:
Get the answer, need to use access iterator directly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you getting error like this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
at beginner.HelloWorldApp.main(HelloWorldApp.java:18)
```

Then you can use an iterator to remove element by this way

```
for(Iterator<Model> iter = userList.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ){

    Model student = iter.next();

    if(student.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("admin"){
        iter.remove();
    }
}

adapter.notifydatasetchange();
```

Comment: `notifydatasetchange()` will refresh all items.. Use `notifyItemRemoved()`

Comment: By using notifyItemRemoved() in the loop it will cause performance issue so I write  notifydatasetchange() change after all items successfully  removed.

Comment: Check that I have added adapter.notifydatasetchange() after loop completion.

Comment: `notifydatasetchange()` will update all items in the adapter which is not needed in case of deletions; why you wish to update whole adapter on item deletions?

Answer (score 2):

Use Iterator

```
int position = 0;

Iterator<User> iter = list.iterator(); 
while (iter.hasNext()) { 
if(iter.next().getRole().equals("admin")){
        iter.remove()
}
position++
}
```

and in adapter

```
adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position)
```

Normal for loop should be used on collections for read only

Comment: adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position) will not be used as we are going to remove every single item with the admin role.it can be lead to performance issues. or if you calling it from outside of the loop it will only update last removed item, not all that have admin role...

Answer (score 1):

You also need to update the `Adapter`. Use something like this:

```
for (int i = userList.size() - 1; i <= userList.size(); ++i) {
    if(userList.get(i).getRole().equals("admin"))
        userList.remove(i);
    adapter.notifyItemRemoved(i)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it still crash. the userList.remove give a warning suspicious List.remove in the loop,and I use this in the adapter class itself.

Comment: what kind of crash is it??

Comment: Sorry look like its my fault. The server return null for the role. But after fix it, it still crash. Need to use iterator directly. Thank You.